# Define Bundle.main.url to use Core Data for iOS9 and above Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm just learning Core Data and I need to implement `Core Data`for both `iOS 9` and `iOS 10` as my only iPad test device is an iPad3 running `iOS 9.3.5`. I'm trying to follow this solution https://charleswilson.blog/2016/09/09/out-of-context-using-core-data-on-ios-9-3-and-10-0/ ( not sure I could paste the whole code from the link ) as I failed with implementing other solutions from stack overflow. I'm not sure If I got this one thing right: Inside the `lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` there is this `let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: modelName, withExtension: modelExtension)!` that I see in other solutions here in stack overflow and they're all declared as with different `String`values for `forResource` parameter, but all with the same `"momd"`value for `withExtension:` parameter. I actually thought the since I'm using an `.xcdatamodeld` I should put in my data model name for `forResource` parameter and `"xcdatamodeld"` for `withExtension:` parameter, resulting in my case as :

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("fix_it_shop").appendingPathExtension("xcdatamodeld")

        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            let dict : [String : Any] = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey        : "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as NSString,
                                         NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data." as NSString,
                                         NSUnderlyingErrorKey             : error as NSError]

            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        }

        return coordinator
    }()
```

Is it so or `withExtension:` parameter is unrelated to my `xcdatamodeld` file extension and I should use `"momd"` instead? Similar questions I found point me in both directions. Many thanks for any explanation you could give about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use “momd” as the file extension for the model.  During the Xcode compilation process, your .xcdatamodeld file gets compiled into a .momd file, which is what actually gets included in the bundle.

However, the `url` variable in the persistentStoreCoordinator definition refers to the `NSPersistentStore` file, which for a sqlite store will have the extension “.sqlite”.

Comment: I'll have to use  `“.sqlite”` than, I'll give it a try thank you so much!

Comment: I have now a little problem. I use to reference `viewContext` using two static variables in `AppDelegate` as `static var persistentContainer`
 but now I can't understand how to return a context for `iOS9` :
`static var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        if #available(iOS 10.0,*){
            return persistentContainer.viewContext
        } else {
            return // what context to return here for iOS 9?
        }
    }` using `databaseContext` gives me the error : `Instance member 'databaseContext' cannot be used on type 'AppDelegate'`. what should I return there instead?